# Split a string in C++ using 2 delimiters '+' & '-"

Tags: c++, c, string, find, delimiter

i am trying to split a string with 2 delimiters '+' and '-' in C++
using a string find a delimiter...

can anyone give me a go around...

Using

> str.find(delimiter)

example :

a+b-c+d

Output Required:
a
b
c
d

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
    std::vector<std::string> v ; //Use vector to add the words

    std::size_t prev_pos = 0, pos;
    while ((pos = str.find_first_of("+-", prev_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (pos > prev_pos)
            v.push_back(str.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos));
        prev_pos= pos+1;
    }
    if (prev_pos< str.length())
        v.push_back(str.substr(prev_pos, std::string::npos));
```

Or if you use `boost` it will be lot easier

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> v;
boost::split(v, line, boost::is_any_of("+-"));
```

Comment: @rolling.stones The first part of the answer is the variant *without* boost. Ignore the second part in your case.

Comment: I am stil not able to use vector / get the splitted output of the code you've mentioned :(

Comment: @rolling.stones and finally you asked to write code for you, and I hate that. See http://ideone.com/UfuG3U. BTW... what did you mean by _"can anyone give me a go around"_ in your post ?

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much @ POW 
You're a saviour !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function "char* strtok(char* src, const char* delimiters)"
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok

```
char* s = "a+b-c+d";
char* p = strtok(s, "+-");  
while (p != NULL)
{
  // do something with p
  p = strtok (NULL, "+-");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for variable delimiters as well

```
void main void()
{
   char stringToUpdate[100] , char delimeters[4];

/*
write code to assign strings and delimeter
*/
        replaceDelimeters(stringToUpdate, delimeters, ' ');
}   

void replaceDelimeters(char* myString, char* delimeters, char repChar)
{   
for (int i = 0; delimeters[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; stringtoUpdate[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
           if(stringtoUpdate[j] == delimeters[i])
           {
                stringtoUpdate[j] = repChar;
           }
        }
    }
}
```